# Replace values in dataframe pertaining only to those matching in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have one dataframe that looks like this:

clientdata

```
account  client   assets
A        bob      1000 
A        frank    1000
A        jim      1000
A        howie    1000
B        bob      2000 
B        frank    2000
B        jim      2000
C        frank    500
C        howie    500
D        bob      250
D        jim      250
D        howie    250
```

and another that looks like this

manualreplace

```
account  assets
B        2150
D        750
```

I want to replace every instance of the assets in the first dataframe with the new amount for every instance where it matches on the account column.

clientdata

```
account  client   assets
A        bob      1000 
A        frank    1000
A        jim      1000
A        howie    1000
B        bob      2150
B        frank    2150
B        jim      2150
C        frank    500
C        howie    500
D        bob      750
D        jim      750
D        howie    750
```

Most of the examples I find are other for replacing 1 instance or replacing values in a dataframe that matches the exact size of the one replacing it.

Any help would be appreciated as I've tried using several variations of .loc, but end up replacing all the values with values in ascending order from the dataframe b, not just exact matches.

edit:
attempts

```
clientdata.loc[clientdata.account.isin(manualdata.account), ['assets']] = manualdata.loc[manualdata.account.isin(clientdata.account), ['assets']].values
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `map` followed by `isna`:

```
clientdata['assets'] = (clientdata['account'].map(manualreplace.set_index('account')['assets'])
                           .fillna(clientdata['assets'])
                       )
```

Output:

```
   account client  assets
0        A    bob  1000.0
1        A  frank  1000.0
2        A    jim  1000.0
3        A  howie  1000.0
4        B    bob  2150.0
5        B  frank  2150.0
6        B    jim  2150.0
7        C  frank   500.0
8        C  howie   500.0
9        D    bob   750.0
10       D    jim   750.0
11       D  howie   750.0
```

Comment: oh man, yes this worked. now i just need to sit around and figure out why. never used map before. thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best way, but it works:

```
df = pd.merge(cd_df, rep_df, how="left", on="account", )
df["assets"] = df["assets_y"]
df.loc[pd.isna(df["assets_y"]), "assets"] = df["assets_x"]
df = df.drop(["assets_x", "assets_y"], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

"update" can be used to get the required result.

```
account = ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C']
client = ['bob','frank','jim','howie','bob','frank','howie','bob','frank']
asset = [1, 2, 3,1,2,3,1,2,3]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'account':account, 'client':client, 'asset':asset})
assets = [100, 110]
account = ['B', 'C']

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'account':account, 'asset':assets})


df1 = df1.set_index('account')
df2 = df2.set_index('account')
df1.update(df2)
df1
```